# Django Heroku on Windows - App crashes repeatedly

Tags: django, heroku

I have been trying to deploy an app to Heroku (no frills, just a simple page) but have not managed to do so. This is my log file -

```
2014-08-03T21:02:53.886884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn      TestApp.wsgi`
2014-08-03T21:02:57.218280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-08-03T21:03:00.994045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 

host=fierce-oasis-7567.herokuapp.com request_id=f53c4902-5a52-4591-a099-ef006a4658d0     fwd="202.78.172.162" 

dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-03T21:03:02.570801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"     method=GET 

path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-oasis-7567.herokuapp.com request_id=22872708-cf36-47b1-    a5e6-552b7a1a8668 

fwd="202.78.172.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-03T21:14:34+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-03T21:15:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-03T21:15:02.272206+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-03T21:15:02.150270+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9b69a49 by     utsav.tiwary2011@gmail.com
2014-08-03T21:15:02.150376+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by     utsav.tiwary2011@gmail.com
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900391+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900398+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.885690+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:06 [2] [INFO] Starting     gunicorn 18.0
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900396+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900402+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900399+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900408+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900404+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900411+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named TestApp.wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900410+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900413+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900419+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900388+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:06 [7] [ERROR] Exception     in worker process:
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900406+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900417+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-08-03T21:15:06.886483+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:06 [2] [INFO] Listening     at: 

http://0.0.0.0:3589 (2)
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900427+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900414+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-


packages/gunicorn/arbit
er.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900416+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900393+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900394+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900420+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:06.896296+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:06 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900421+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900428+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900401+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900407+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900423+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900429+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900431+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named TestApp.wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:07.024019+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:07 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900424+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-08-03T21:15:07.024128+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:07 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2014-08-03T21:15:06.886586+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:06 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900425+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-08-03T21:15:06.900514+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:06 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2014-08-03T21:15:05.633019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn TestApp.wsgi`
2014-08-03T21:15:08.072497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-08-03T21:15:08.083536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-03T21:15:08.084259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-03T21:15:11.225689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn TestApp.wsgi`
2014-08-03T21:15:12.151723+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166252+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166257+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166251+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166249+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166260+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166246+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166256+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166265+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166259+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166262+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166254+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166263+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166273+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, i
n spawn_worker
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166271+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166275+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166287+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166266+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166281+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166268+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166289+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named TestApp.wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166274+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166278+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166269+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named TestApp.wsgi
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166285+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166283+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2014-08-03T21:15:12.152842+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166277+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166282+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166279+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-08-03T21:15:12.152750+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [2] [INFO] Listening at: 

http://0.0.0.0:28415 (2)
2014-08-03T21:15:12.287650+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2014-08-03T21:15:12.287529+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166286+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
2014-08-03T21:15:12.166363+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2014-08-03T21:15:12.162414+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-08-03 21:15:12 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-08-03T21:15:15.136154+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 

host=fierce-oasis-7567.herokuapp.com request_id=86c520f6-3c60-4817-a006-7d5111a22a3c fwd="54.83.118.7" dyno= 

connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-03T21:15:13.398231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-03T21:15:13.379837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
```

And this is my Procfile :

```
web: gunicorn TestApp.wsgi
```

This is my requirements.txt

```
Django<=1.3.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
psycopg2==2.4.5
gunicorn==18.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
dj-static==0.0.5
static==0.4
```

This is my settings file:

```
    # Django settings for TestApp project.

import os
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"

# Additional locations of static files

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'n(bd1f1c%e8=_xad02x5qtfn%wgwpi492e$8_erx+d)!tpeoim'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TestApp.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TestApp.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gunicorn',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Procfile : **web: sh -c "cd TestApp && gunicorn TestApp.wsgi"**

Basically, my error is that it is not able to locate TestApp.wsgi and hence crashes every time. I followed the following steps while deploying -

- git add -A.
- git commit -m"commit"
- git push heroku master
- git ps

Can anyone please help me figure out what is wrong ? Thanks in advance ! (Please let me know if any other file/detail
 is needed)

Comment: That tree gives lots of irrelevant information and none of the actually useful information. Where is TestApp.wsgi? Where is your requirements.txt file? What about the actual code of your Django app?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thankyou sir. I'll edit the question right away !

Comment: @DanielRoseman The requirements.txt is present in the correct folder and installs all the dependencies when the project is pushed. Although, I do think the *.wsgi is missing. What is my .wsgi supposed to contain ?

Comment: What is the output of `git status TestApp.wsgi`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks for replying. It says - **.Nothing to commit.Working Directory Clean**